# Android - How to access state of checkboxes in fragments from activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, checkbox, save

So I have a class which has a tabbed layout of 4 fragments each with a list of checkboxes. I need to save the state of those checkboxes in a sqlite database, but I am not able to access them at all with findViewById from the activity (throws a nullpointerexception). How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first add or replace any fragment.. add a tag for it.. then later use this is acticity

```
fragment f1 = getfragmentmanager.findfragmentByTag("tag1");
```

then you can get and save

```
f1.getCheckbox1().ischecked()...
```

amd so on... 
 you can use getFragmentManager.getFragments...

Comment: How would I do this if I am working with a viewpager instead? I don't use transactions at all, so there isn't an add or replace used.

Comment: use Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":"+indexPage);

Comment: you may have to use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager()... depends on how did you define your pagerAdapter

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but the problem I have is that I don't know where to add the tag...

Comment: you dont add the tag... the viewpager add the tags to its fragments

Comment: it is doing that.. all what you have to do is to get the visible fragment.. using what i told you in the previous comment

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

You can't access view elements in your fragment from your activity, it simply wasn't created for this. And why would you need to?

You can simply save the values of your checkboxes inside your fragment code, where you have full access to the entire view. You can still access your sqlite database inside a fragment, it doesn't have to be an activity.

Answer (score 0):

In a fragment you can override the onCreateView and inflate the view.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.testelement);
    return v;
}
```

And find the elements by doing this.